# Pink IntelliJ theme

Tags: intellij-idea, themes

Is there a pink intelliJ theme out there?
I can't find anything, like I need the background to be pink. maybe theres some configuration script that I could edit, how could I achieve this?

Comment: What about https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12334-gradianto/ dark fuchsia?

Comment: dark fuchisa looks almost what I want just a lighter theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at  [Material Theme UI](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8006-material-theme-ui) it's the closest to what you're looking for.

enjoy it